# scala.collection.immutable.Vector cannot be cast to <My Class>

Tags: scala, vector, functional-programming, classcastexception, immutable-collections

I am perplexed why I cannot yield a collection from the following line of Scala code:

```
val pairs = for( v <- vc; o <- oc) yield (v,o)
```

It's inside of this function, which is using immutable Vectors.

```
 private def recMergeVirtualAndReal(mCell: RCell, vc: Vector[Cell], oc: Vector[Cell]): Vector[Cell] = {
        var temp_oc = oc
        val pairs = for( v <- vc; o <- oc) yield (v,o)
        val newVCells =
          for((left, right) <- pairs if left contains right) yield {
            temp_oc = temp_oc.filterNot(o => o == left || o == right)
            captureVCells(left,right,mCell)
          }
        if(newVCells.nonEmpty) recMergeVirtualAndReal(mCell, recMergeVirtualCells(newVCells ++ vc), temp_oc)
        else vc
      }
```

I get the following error in the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Vector cannot be cast to game.Cell
    at model.Board$$anonfun$10.apply(Board.scala:223)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:327)
```

I'm confused because I am not trying to cast anything, its just a simple statement without any type conversions.

I also tried this in case the compiler couldn't understand the types:

```
val pairs = for( v: Cell <- vc: Vector[Cell]; o: Cell <- oc: Vector[Cell]) yield (v: Cell,o: Cell)
```

Comment: This isn't really a proper [mcve]. I can't paste it into my REPL and run it, as stuff is missing. That's why I can only guess at your problem in my answer.

Comment: Which line is 223?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably doing an unsafe cast somewhere in the calling code. Check the arguments to your function, and check especially for uses of `asInstanceOf`.

Here's an example of how an unsafe cast could cause this problem. First, we create a `List[Int]`, then force the compiler to think of it as a `List[String]`.

```
val ls = List(1).asInstanceOf[List[String]]
```

This works, as the Scala compiler is okay with it, and the generics are unchecked at runtime until we try to store an element of the list to a variable:

```
val x = ls.head  // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.String
```

Probably, somewhere else in your code, you are calling `.asInstanceOf[Vector[Cell]]` on a `Vector[Vector[Something]]`, then passing it to this function. Never use `asInstanceOf` if you can help it.